# How to join oracle table valued function?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, join

Is is possible to join Oracle table valued function?
i want query and inner join fuction. How to join?

**Query Oracle**

```
FUNCTION FNC_LST_OUR(p_code   varchar2,
                     p_pm_from  varchar2,
                     p_pm_to   varchar2                                  
                    ) return VARCHAR2 is                                 

v_sql2 VARCHAR2(30000) := '';
v_sql VARCHAR2(30000) := '';
number_out NUMBER := 0;      
error_msg_tmp varchar2(255);

begin
      v_sql := 'select s.com_code, s.pn_code, count(*) as our   
                from pmtest s 
                inner join PMOP_TEST l on s.com_code=l.com_code and s.pn_code=l.pn_code
                where s.com_code = ''' || p_code ||
                '; 

      if p_pm_from is not null then
        v_sql := v_sql || ' and s.pn_code between ''' || p_pm_from || ''' and ''' || p_pm_to || '''';
      end if;

        v_sql := v_sql || ' group by s.com_code,s.pn_code
                            having count(s.pn_code)> 0 ';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_sql2;   
      RETURN v_sql2;

      exception
      when OTHERS THEN
        error_msg_tmp := substr(sqlcode || ' - ' || sqlerrm, 1, 200);
        RETURN v_sql2;      
end;
```

**Statement Query**

```
   select a.*
   from PMOP_TEST l
   inner join table(packages.FNC_LST_OUR('test','test','test')) a on l.com_code=a.com_code and a.pn_code=l.pn_code
```

**Error Query on statement : ORA-22905**

**Sample Data Function**

```
com_code | pn_code | OUR
AAA      | AW      |0
AAA      | AQ      |5
AAB      | AQ      |10
AAA      | CV      |2
```

**Sampla Data Statement Table PMOP_TEST**

```
com_code | pn_code | DESCRIPT
AAA      | AW      | test1
AAA      | AQ      | test2
AAB      | AQ      | test2
AAA      | CV      | test3
AAB      | FG      | test1
```

**i want join function value result:**

```
com_code | pn_code | DESCRIPT | OUR
AAA      | AW      | test1    | 0
AAA      | AQ      | test2    | 5
AAA      | CV      | test3    | 2
```

Help me please. thanks advance ;)

Comment: Your function will not work. You are selecting tree fields into one (v_sql2). If you want to use the function in such way make a pipeline function.

Comment: This error means you are selecting from unsupported table. You can create type as table and can return that table instead of varchar.

Comment: @Mottor How use pipeline function

Comment: On a side note: Your `HAVING` clause makes no sense; it is always true. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner if pn_code is null, is not true, If nettoon493 means it, is another question.

Comment: @Mottor: `s.pn_code` can never be null, because of `and s.pn_code=l.pn_code`.

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamic query can be represented in SQL like this (specifying the inputs as bind variables):

```
select s.com_code, s.pn_code, count(*) as our   
from   pmtest s 
       inner join PMOP_TEST l
       on (s.com_code=l.com_code and s.pn_code=l.pn_code)
where  s.com_code = :p_code
and    ( :p_pm_from IS NULL OR s.pn_code between :p_pm_from and :p_pm_to )
group by s.com_code,s.pn_code
```

Then you can join it to your other query like this:

```
select a.*
from   PMOP_TEST l
       inner join (
         select s.com_code,
                s.pn_code,
                count(*) as our   
         from   pmtest s 
                inner join PMOP_TEST l
                on (s.com_code=l.com_code and s.pn_code=l.pn_code)
         where  s.com_code = :p_code
         and    ( :p_pm_from IS NULL OR s.pn_code between :p_pm_from and :p_pm_to )
         group by s.com_code,s.pn_code
       ) a
       on l.com_code=a.com_code and a.pn_code=l.pn_code
```

And you have done it all with SQL and don't need to use collections or pipelined queries.

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
CREATE TYPE FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
   com_code VARCHAR2 (20),
   pn_code VARCHAR2 (20),
   our NUMBER
);
/
CREATE TYPE FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE_T AS TABLE OF FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg
AS
   FUNCTION FNC_LST_OUR (p_code VARCHAR2, p_pm_from VARCHAR2, p_pm_to VARCHAR2)
      RETURN FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE_T
      PIPELINED;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg
AS
   FUNCTION FNC_LST_OUR (p_code VARCHAR2, p_pm_from VARCHAR2, p_pm_to VARCHAR2)
      RETURN FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE_T
      PIPELINED
   IS
      c          SYS_REFCURSOR;
      v_result   FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE;
   BEGIN
      OPEN c FOR 'select FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE(''AAA'' , ''AW'' , 0 ) from dual
               union all
               select FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE(''AAA'' , ''AQ'' , 5) from dual
               union all
               select FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE(''AAB'' , ''AQ'' , 10) from dual
               union all
               select FNC_LST_OUR_TYPE(''AAA'' , ''CV'', 2) from dual';

      LOOP
         FETCH c INTO v_result;

         EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
         PIPE ROW (v_result);
      END LOOP;
   END;
END;
/
```

And use it:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ( PKG.FNC_LST_OUR ('A', 'B', 'C') )
```

Look at [Table Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a pipelined function that returns a table of records. In order to write it you need a record type for the columns the function is to return and a table type for the rows:

```
create or replace type fnc_lst_our_record is record(com_code number, pn_code number, our number);
create or replace type fnc_lst_our_table is table of fnc_lst_our_record;
```

Then write the function using the types. You don't need any dynamic SQL for this by the way.

```
create or replace function fnc_lst_our
(
  p_code   varchar2,
  p_pm_from  varchar2,
  p_pm_to   varchar2                                  
) return fnc_lst_our_table pipelined is 
begin
  for rec in
  (
    select s.com_code, s.pn_code, count(*) as our   
    from pmtest s 
    inner join pmop_test l on s.com_code = l.com_code and s.pn_code = l.pn_code
    where s.com_code = p_code
    and (p_pm_from is null or p_pm_from s.pn_code between p_pm_from and p_pm_to)
    group by s.com_code,s.pn_code
    having count(s.pn_code) > 0 -- this clause is superfluous
  ) loop
    pipe fnc_lst_our_record(rec.com_code, rec.pn_code, rec.our);
  end loop;  
end;
```

You call this function exactly as you tried.